# Extracting Part of Speech (Source and Destinations) using text mining/NLP?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, text-mining, natural-language, information-retrieval

> I need to extract the source and destination terms from the text
>   documents using text mining/NLP/Information Retrieval ?

ex :

> 1. i am travelling from New York to London.
> 2. i am heading towards playground from home.
> 3. i will be going to Sweden from Boston.
> 4. i was flying from School to Home.

the output can be as follows :

```
S. No. |  source    | Destination
------ |  ----------|------------
      1| New York   | London
      2| playground | home
      3| Sweden     | Boston
      4| School     | Home
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, you need two things.

The first is an **entity recognizer** that detects terms in the text referencing locations. Since you have custom entities like *"home"*, a standard named entity recognizer like [Apache OpenNLP](https://opennlp.apache.org/) will most likely not be sufficient without retraining.

The second is a model that tells you which of the detected terms is the source and which the destination, e.g. `isSource("home") = 0` and `isDestination("home")` = 1. You can try to train a classification model or a **relation extraction** model for this task on your own using labelled instances. But for a start I would recommend checking out [MITIE](https://github.com/mit-nlp/MITIE), an information extraction library providing named entity recognition and binary relation extraction tools. Note that it also comes with an interactive model training tool.